# Trouble with play framework hot reloading in vagrant

Tags: macos, scala, playframework, vagrant

I'm running a play scala application on an ubuntu vagrant virtual machine (xenial64) on a mac OSX host. I run the application with `sbt ~run`

When I make a change to a file, I see a log statement saying that the code is compiling:

`[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /vagrant/web/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Compiled in 1s`

However, when I visit an url in my browser, such as `http://localhost:9000/hello`, it gets stuck on the return value that is returned the first time I visit it. For example, if it returns `"hello"` the first time I visit it and I change the code to return `"hello again"`, I will still see `"hello"`.

However, if I change the code *before* the first time I visit the url and after starting the server, I will see the changed version.

The weird thing is that this seems to be on an url-by-url basis. So if one url is "stuck" and I can't change the return value, I can still change the return value in code to an url I haven't visited yet. Only when I first visit it in the browser will its value be fixed.

This *sounds* like a browser caching issue, but it's not. I turned off browser caching, and even tried hitting the same url in a different browser. The value was still stuck.

But every time I change the code, I do see a recompiling message.

What is going on?

Comment: can you run `curl -v http://localhost:9000/hello` for first and second time, make sure you have no cache control